# Genymotion Device doesn't appear on Device Chooser - Android Studio

Tags: android, genymotion

I installed Genymotion with a virtual Box and the Genymotion plugin (Android Studio), created a new device and runs properly, even from Android Studio.

However when I hit the Run button, the Genymotion device does not appear on the Device Chooser, it says '**Nothing to Show**' under the 'Choose a running device' radio button. How can I get the Genymotion device to appear on the Device Chooser and run my app? Is it something I am missing from the SDK manager?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. Started to happen after I updated Studio to 2.1 Preview 3

Comment: @FAST it's not true in case talking about newest android studio emulators, because them completely replace whole genymotion features and have competable performance

Answer (score 194):

This happens because Genymotion is shipped with outdated Android tools. To solve follow the steps:

- Open Genymotion app,
- Go to Settings -> ADB
- Select 'Use custom Android SDK tools'
- And select location of your Android SDK.

On Mac with a recent version of Studio that would be:

```
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/
```

Comment: Hi Anton, What is stock emulator?

Comment: It's a regular Android emulator. You can create it via Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager

Comment: This worked for me on Genymotion 2.6.0 and Android Studio 2.1:

`/Users/username/Android`

Comment: on my machine the path was C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Comment: Very helpful, thanks.  Just to add some info: In Android Studio, open Tools > Android > SDK Manager.  The displayed screen will show the location of the Android SDK that Android Studio is using. That is the directory location that you want to enter into the Genymotion settings.

Comment: Accept as answer please. It's the right way to make it work (Android Studio with Genymotion 2.11.0)

Comment: I restarted my Genymotion after this process and it worked

Answer (score 46):

I had the same problem,
but I solved it.

Before running `genymotion` you have to first click on run and wait until project compile and show you the empty device list and then you have to start your `genymotion`, after that it will appear.

1. click the run button to compile project
2. device empty list appear
3. start `genymotion`
4. device will appear in the list

That worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks! To be clear, when I did it, I opened the Genymotion emulator using the Genymotion plugin for Android Studio.

Answer (score 18):

Got the same issue on AS 3.3.2, I tried to select location of the Android SDK, or kill / restart the server. Still they didn't work.

After that, I install the **genymotion** plugin in AS and open the genymotion device manager, then check the actual **ip address** of the active genymotion device.

[image]

```
adb connect device_ip_address:5555
```

Now the device can be detected on device chooser.

P.S. Thanks @Ismail Iqbal for pointing out that the genymotion plugin is not necessary. You can also get the ip address from the emulator header.

Comment: No need to install genymotion plugin for this. you can get the ip from the genymotion emulator header

Comment: this worked for me: adb connect device_ip_address:device_port
ex: adb connect 192.168.1.1:5555

Comment: Thank you. I just got it working by connecting to it manually.

Comment: adb is found at <android-sdk-path>/platform-tools/. Worked for me, thank you! However, it requires this process every time I restart Genymotion, any fix for it?

Answer (score 9):

I also am facing the same issue in new version of Android studio. following is my routine that everyday i am doing to solve this issue:

1. Click Run icon to see empty list of device
2. Close this list
3. Kill adb by:

   ```
   adb kill-server
   ```

   Sometime you need to run this command twice.
4. Start adb again by:

   ```
   adb start-server
   ```
5. Click run again. Now I will see list of my emulators but not my Genymotion that is already up and running!
6. I will add my Genymotion by:

   ```
   adb connect 192.168.56.101
   ```

   This command has to be run when select device dialog is still open.

Now everything will be OK.

Comment: Hi, I followed the steps above, but it still doesn't show my Genymotion device.

Comment: About the step 6, the command should be : adb connect 192.168.56.101:5555 in your case.

Answer (score 7):

On **Android Studio 2** :

1. Click on button "*Attach debugger to Android process*" on **Toolbar**.
2. Click **restart**.
3. Try run again.

Goodluck.

Answer (score 5):

1. Tools->Android-> Remove check "Enable ADB Integration"
2. Run your app with appeared device.( you will get an error)
3. Set check "Enable ADB Integration"
4. Run your app

Answer (score 5):

You can solve it quickly.

First make sure that ***genymotion emulator is opend.***

> 1. close device chooser (On andoid studio)
> 2. open task manager(on windows ctrl + shift + esc)
> 3. pick process tab
> 4. find adb.exe maybe its adb.exe*32
> 5. right click and select kill process tree
> 6. adb will again appear shortly kill its process tree again( maybe
>      more than one adb will be found kill all.)
> 7. then open device chooser (click run on android studio).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This actually worked for me! ONLY one thing i did differently. My GenyMotion was closed. Then i killed the entire ADB tree processes(there were 3 of them)... And then when i restarted the Genymotion, it automatically appeared in the Connected devices.

Answer (score 2):

I solved mine by:

First start android studio before starting genymotion. Then run the app in android studio and wait until you see the device chooser  then start genymotion

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone is still looking for an answer. The software versions in which i faced the 
 above issuue is -

**Android Studio - 3.3.2 

Genymotion - 3.0.1**

So, now let's start with the problem. Just try the following steps:

1. Check if you have enabled **Genymotion Plugin** in Android Studio. For Windows, go to 
    **File** -> **Settings** -> **Plugins** -> **Search for Genymotion** and see if it is checked. If you can't find it, Click on **Browse repositories** , search for **Genymotion** and install it.

   Check the tick in the plugin:

   [image: Check the tick in the plugin]
2. Check if the Genymotion Emulator is running or not and **Genymotion Main Screen** shows status as **Running** or **ON**
   (This was my problem. Although my emulator was up and running but Genymotion's Status was showing Booting). It usually takes some time to get the **status** from **Booting** to **ON**

   Check for emulator status:

   [image: Check for emulator status]
3. Check if your Min SDK Version is less than the Emulator's SDK Version. I faced it quite a lot in my initial days. For that, Go to your **Module:app** gradle file and see the **Min SDK Version** and the **Emulators SDK Version** is same or higher.

   **Check for Min SDK Version as highlighted in the image:**
   [image: **Check for Min SDK Version as highlighted in the image**]

Hope this helps. If you still get any problem do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

When you close the device, it is no longer available to the device chooser.  You need to keep running the device from Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `adb kill-server/start-server`. But, It didn't worked.

Instead hitting this command 2-3 times quickly worked.

```
adb reconnect
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the genymotion path was not set ..so I solved it by clicking the genymotion icon from the tool bar and enter the path (the default in windows is C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion) then after starting the emulator it now appears in android studio

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to run the genymotion from the android studio by pressing the genymotion icon after genymotion starts then press the run button, you will see the genymotion device option on deployment target dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers of this question :

My problem was about **windows viruses** , Last days i turned off my **windows defender**  and i have't any other antivirus software in my system .

My **SDK** folder was **full of virus** , when i scanned Many viruses detected .

After removing viruses from my PC i had to remove **SDK** completely and download it again .

> Finally notice that : For any reason , if the **SDK** files are
>   damaged may cause this error .

**Now the problem is solved** .

Answer (score 0):

For This Problem:

1. Go to Project structure/project
2. In project SDK select simulator API version.
3. Done. Now your genydevice is added in the list.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I've tried from the android studio version 2.0  and the version 2.1, both does not compitable to genymotion. please use the version 1.5.1 or older than that.