# App does not start in Genymotion

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

i have installed Genymotion recently, and everything is fine, but when I click on run icon in Android Studio, it asks to create AVD.

I want to test my app using Genymotion virtual device.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the Genymotion plugin for the IDE.

> To install the Genymotion plugin for Android Studio.
>
> In Android Studio, go to File/Settings (for Windows and Linux) or to Android Studio/Preferences (for Mac OS X)
>
> 1. Select Plugins and click Browse Repositories.
> 2. Right-click on Genymotion and click Download and install. To see Genymotion plugin icon, display the toolbar by clicking View > Toolbar.

Source: https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/

Comment: Its already installed and Generation plugin icon is displaying on the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

This guide for running app might help - [Running an App in the Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html#runningapp).
Follow those steps, so you would be able to see the `Select Deployment Target` dialog.
Pay attention to the fact that your genymotion emulator should appear under the list of `Connected Devices` (and not under the list of `Available Virtual Devices`).
If you can't see your genymotion emulator on that list, please refer to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27262104/6253504).

Answer (score 0):

Have you created any virtual devices on GenyMotion. You should have a virtual device to run an app.[image]

If you have virtual devices and they stop running on start, download Oracle VM Virtual Machine [using this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html) I have this issue if i use the VM installed via GenyMotion. If you install VM using link, it can say VM is older but it works, otherwise it does not.

Comment: I have multiple projects (apps) and I realized that  Genymotion woks with all of them and does not work with only one specific project. what is wrong with that project?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,

the genymotion device should be shown on the device chooser window, when clicking on 'run' icon in android studio but it doesn't...

in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261474/android-studio-doesnt-see-genymotion), your question is answered (but not such effective).

**SOLUTION 1:**

To solve this, follow the following steps.

- open Genymotion app,
- go to Settings -> ADB
- select 'Use custom Android SDK tools'
- and select location of your SDK.

the default location of sdk tools on `Windows`:

```
C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local\Android
```

tip: pay attention that 'AppData' folder might be hidden.

the default location of sdk tools on `Mac`:

```
/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
```

[image description for the solution 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpA3k.png)

**SOLUTION 2:**

you can use a simple trick:

1. turn on your genymotion device (by clicking on the genymotion icon,
   right of the bar and choosing your desired device)
2. close device chooser (On andoid studio)
3. open task manager(on windows ctrl + shift + esc)
4. pick 'process' tab
5. find 'adb.exe' maybe its 'adb.exe*32'
6. right click and select kill process tree (or End Task)
7. adb will again appear shortly kill its process tree again( maybe
   more than one adb will be found kill all.)
8. then open device chooser (click run on android studio).

Bingo, your intended device is appeared.

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41541471/7076130) leads you for more explanations

**SOLUTION 3:**

update your genymotion and virtualbox.(I did this but it didn't worked for me, it might be effective for you)

`my suggestion is solution 2 to do!`

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem 
i am just new to android development even first day.

just go to menu bar and  Run > Attach Debugger to Android Process than [dialog after selection that option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYWuV.png)

find the process com.android.launcher and hit ok

than normally Click on Play icon to Run the Project it will Run on Genymotion