# Visual Studio for Mac and Genymotion

Tags: visual-studio, genymotion, visual-studio-mac

I've used Genymotion as my android emulator for years because it is faster and better for me.  With the most recent major update to VSMac, VS no longer recognizes a running genymotion emulator.  I have genymotion 3.01.  Any ideas on what is happening and what I should do to get this to work?

TIA.

Comment: follow the answer by Anton
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36243787

Comment: @JosueMartinez Thanks.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to the virtual device manually using adb:

`adb connect {ENTER_IP_OF_EMULATOR_HERE}:5555`